# Kendo charts tooltip not at correct location, for more than one chart in a viewer

Tags: angular, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo Bar and Line chart for showing data. I have my viewer configurable. Such as I can configure multiple charts with different data on a single viewer(which is a dashboard).

Refer to image attached, the tooltip is not shown at correct location.

I then checked it on the Kendo's site for example, and found the issue there as well. (refer to the images[2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOlx1.png) and [1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M43KY.png))

Code used by me is as below:
The issue is same for any charts configured. Tooltip for pie is also not visible at correct location. Code below

```
<kendo-chart-legend [visible]="chart.Data.showLegend" position="top"></kendo-chart-legend>
<kendo-chart-title id="chartTitle"
                   [visible]="chart.Options.title.display" [text]="chart.Options.title.text">
</kendo-chart-title>

<kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="chart.Data.labels"
                                    [labels]="{ rotation: 'auto' }"
                                    [title]="chart.Options.XTitle">
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-category-axis>

<kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="chart.Options.YTitle">
    </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-value-axis>

<kendo-chart-series (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)">
    <span *ngFor="let dataset of chart.Data.datasets">
        <kendo-chart-series-item [name]="dataset.label" [data]="dataset.data"
                                 [type]="dataset.type">
            <kendo-chart-series-item-labels visible="true" [content]="setLabelFormat">

            </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>    
        </kendo-chart-series-item>

    </span>

</kendo-chart-series>
```

Comment: Kendo UI for Angular 2 is just in first beta. It's probably a bug and as a beta tester you may want to report it directly to Telerik. Also, what browser are you using, as I was just on the demo site and the tooltips seem to appear in the correct spot for me on chrome.

Comment: I am also running on Chrome.